# Python - how slice([1,2,3]) works and what does slice(None, [1, 3], None) represent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

[Documentation for `class slice(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice%20function#slice):

> Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by range(start, stop, step).

What is going in the code and why the slice class init even allows a list as its argument?

```
print(slice([1,3]))
---
slice(None, [1, 3], None)

print(slice(list((1,3))))
---
slice(None, [1, 3], None)  # why stop is list?

hoge = [1,2,3,4]
_s = slice(list((1,3)))
print(hoge[_s])
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-1b2df30e9bdf> in <module>
      1 hoge = [1,2,3,4]
      2 _s = slice(list((1,3)))
----> 3 print(hoge[_s])

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

---

## Updae

Thanks to the answer from Selcuk.

[sliceobject.c#L303-L322](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/sliceobject.c#L303-L322)

```
static PyObject *
slice_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw)
{
    PyObject *start, *stop, *step;

    start = stop = step = NULL;

    if (!_PyArg_NoKeywords("slice", kw))
        return NULL;

    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "slice", 1, 3, &start, &stop, &step))
        return NULL;

    /* This swapping of stop and start is to maintain similarity with
       range(). */
    if (stop == NULL) {
        stop = start;       // <-----
        start = NULL;
    }
      
    return PySlice_New(start, stop, step);  // PySlice_New in L110 in the same file
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice%20function#slice):

> Slice objects have read-only data attributes `start`, `stop` and `step` which merely return the argument values (or their default). They have no other explicit functionality [...]

So they are simply dummy objects that keep whatever you pass them. You can even pass strings or other objects:

```
my_slice = slice("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

> [...] however they are used by Numerical Python and other third party extensions.

It is the third party extension's job to validate if the `start`, `stop`, and `step` values make any sense.

Also see the [CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/sliceobject.c#L110).

When you only pass one argument it is assumed to be the `stop` value. That's why you end up with `start` and `step` values set to `None`:

> `class slice(stop)`
>
> `class slice(start, stop[, step])`

Comment: Thanks for the code pointer. I suppose the documentation "The start and step arguments default to None" indicates "only one arg goes to stop". I think the c code itself does not tell so and the another doc https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html#c.PySlice_New also looks not specific either...

Comment: Since numpy apparently takes a list as a slice expression ```np.arange(5)[[1,2]]```, getting confused if it is python or numpy. I suppose it is numpy specific implementation.

Comment: It is explicitly stated in the docs with the alternative constructor: `class slice(stop)`. It is tricky to see that in the C code but have a look at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/sliceobject.c#L316